# Delete files 100 at a time and count total files

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a bash script to delete 100 files at a time from a directory because i was getting **args list too long** error but now i want to count the total files that were deleted in total from the directory

Here is the script

```
echo /example-dir/* | xargs -n 100 rm -rf
```

What i want is to write the total deleted files from each directory into a file along with path for example `Deleted <count> files from <path>`

How can i achieve this with my current setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `xargs` and do this in a simple `while` loop and use a counter:

```
destdir='/example-dir/'
count=0

while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    rm -rf "$file"
    ((count++))
done < <(find "$destdir" -type f -print0)

echo "Deleted $count files from $destdir"
```

Note use of `-print0` to take care of file names with whitespaces/newlines/glob etc.

Comment: I am getting error with your script 
./file.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./file.sh: line 9: `    done < <(find "$destdir" -type f -print0)'

Comment: That error means you're not executing it using `bash`. Make sure you use `bash`

Comment: I am executing it in gitbash

Comment: ok try: `find "$destdir" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    rm -rf "$file"
    ((count++))
done`

Comment: There is still an issue. I tried both on gitbash and linux and its raising error

Comment: ./file.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./file.sh: line 5: `    find "$destdir" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file; do rm -rf "$file" ((count++)) done'

Comment: Thanks now everything is working fine but the count it displays is always zero. I counted the files before deletion there were 45 files. It deleted all of them but in my log.txt file it juts displayed Deleted 0 files from directory-name

Comment: Ah it is due to pipiline. Use: `count=$(find "$destdir" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file; do rm -vf "$file"; done | wc -l); echo "Deleted $count files from $destdir" > status.file`

Comment: Please update the main answer if possible, as it will be helpful to others as i have marked it the right answer

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this by enabling verbose output from `rm` and then simply count the output lines using `wc -l`

If you have whitespaces or special characters in the file names, using `echo` to pass the list of files to `xargs` will not work.

Better use `find` with `-print0` to use a NULL character as a delimiter for the individual files:

```
find /example-dir -type f -print0  | xargs --null -n 100 rm -vrf | wc -l
```

Comment: Actually i need to delete recursively all files and folders inside the specified folder. will it work with your example?
Moreover i need to write the total files deleted to a log.txt files if i cat it with your example it writes to log,txt for every file deleted. How can i just cat to file with >> with total count when all files are deleted?

Comment: Yes, it works recursively. I have edited my answer to show the number of deleted files. To append it to a file: `find /example-dir -type f -print0 | xargs --null -n 100 rm -vrf | wc -l >> file.txt`, but you probably know that :)

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you really have lots of files and you do this often, it might be useful to look at some other options:

#### Use `find`'s built-in `-delete`

```
time find . -name \*.txt -print -delete  | wc -l
   30000

real    0m1.244s
user    0m0.055s
sys     0m1.037s
```

#### Use `find`'s ability to build up maximal length argument list

```
time find . -name \*.txt -exec rm -v {} + | wc -l
   30000

real    0m0.979s
user    0m0.043s
sys     0m0.920s
```

#### Use GNU Parallel's ability to build long argument lists

```
time find . -name \*.txt -print0 | parallel -0 -X rm -v | wc -l
   30000

real    0m1.076s
user    0m1.090s
sys     0m1.223s
```

#### Use a single Perl process to read filenames and delete whilst counting

```
time find . -name \*.txt -print0 | perl -0ne 'unlink;$i++;END{print $i}'
30000
real    0m1.049s
user    0m0.057s
sys     0m1.006s
```

For testing, you can create 30,000 files really fast with **GNU Parallel**, which allows `-X` to also build up long argument lists. For example, I can create 30,000 files in 8 seconds on my Mac with:

```
seq -w 0 29999 | parallel -X touch file{}.txt
```